# Check if key exists in JSON object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have done AJAX validation and validated message is returned as a JSON  array. Therefore I need to check whether the keys, like `name` and `email`, are in that JSON array.

```
{
    "name": {
        "isEmpty": "Value is required and can't be empty"
    },
    "email": {
        "isEmpty": "Value is required and can't be empty"
    }
}
```

Only if the key name is present, I need to write an error message to the `name` field.

Following is the code to display an error if fields is entered

```
if (obj['name']'isEmpty'] != "") {                                 
   $('#name').after(c1 + "<label class='error'>" + obj['name']['isEmpty'] + "</label>");
}                                       
if (obj['email']['isEmpty'] != "" ) { 
   $('#email').after(c4 + "<label class='error'>" + obj['email']['isEmpty'] + "</label>");
}
```

But if the `name` field is entered, it will not be in JSON array.
So the checking statement

```
if (obj['name']['isEmpty'] != "")
```

will result in the following error:

> obj.name not found

It is not necessary to have key `name` in  the array. At same time I need to check for this to display the error if the array possesses the key `name`.

Answer (score 112):

Use JavaScript's [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) function:

```
if (json_object.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
    //do necessary stuff
}
```

Comment: it returns false either cases of array has key 'name' nor it doesnt have key 'name'.according to user the fill form the array have  elemnts name or email

Comment: it return true is key exists and false if not exists

Comment: @Dau, for completeness, it actually checks whether the supplied property exists on that object at its link in its prototype chain. Since javascript is prototypical, other objects can extend from other objects by inheriting their prototype. Checking `hasOwnProperty` ensures you are not "dredging up" items from higher in an object's prototype chain.

Answer (score 18):

No need of JQuery simply you can do

```
if(yourObject['email']){
 // what if this property exists.
}
```

as with any value for `email` will return you `true`, if there is no such property or that property value is `null` or `undefined` will result to `false`

Comment: What if the value of `email` was `0`, or `false`, or an empty string? The property does exist, but this will say it doesn't.

Comment: This will also result in a false positive for things like `yourObject['toString']`. Use `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: hasownproperty result false despite the name exisit or not

Comment: instead of if(obj['name']['isEmpty']!="") use if(obj.hasOwnProperty('name') && obj.name.hasOwnProperty('isEmpty') && obj.name.isEmpty != "")

Answer (score 14):

```
if(typeof theObject['key'] != 'undefined'){
     //key exists, do stuff
}

//or

if(typeof theObject.key != 'undefined'){
    //object exists, do stuff
}
```

I'm writing here because no one seems to give the right answer..

I know it's old...

Somebody might question the same thing..

Comment: Thanks, very helpful solution.

Answer (score 3):

if you have an array

```
var subcategories=[{name:"test",desc:"test"}];

function hasCategory(nameStr) {
        for(let i=0;i<subcategories.length;i++){
            if(subcategories[i].name===nameStr){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

if you have an object

```
var category={name:"asd",test:""};

if(category.hasOwnProperty('name')){//or category.name!==undefined
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
```